# how to keep my footer at the bottom using position relative { background-color: #2E3639; position: relative; z-index: 1; }

Tags: html, css

how to keep my footer at the bottom using position relative

footer
{     background-color: #2E3639;     position: relative;     z-index: 1;  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap your footer with a relative div.

.wrapper {
   position: relative;
}

footer {
   position:fixed;
   bottom:0;
}

< div class=“wrapper”>
   < footer>Footer< /footer>
< /div>